# Error:cannot find input file: `man/Makefile.in'

Tags: software-installation, compiling, python-2.7, configure

I was trying to install `hdf4` and then `python-hdf4`. I am new to both Linux and Python. I need to read the hdf file. I though I need to install `pyhdf` since http://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-read-a-MODIS-HDF-file-using-python-/ has used the `pyhdf` module for reading pyhdf file.

At first I tried installing using command `pip install pyhdf` and got the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhdf (from versions): No matching distribution found for pyhdf.

Then I downloaded `pyhdf-0.9.0` and I tried to install it. When I try to compile while installing `hdf-4.2.12`, I got the error:

```
pyhdf/hdfext_wrap.c:3543:17: fatal error: hdf.h: No such file or directory
```

After searching the error using the question [Install pyhdf error: hdf.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157914/install-pyhdf-error-hdf-h-no-such-file-or-directory) I did as the file said:

1. I downloaded pyhdf from http://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf4/.
2. Then I followed the link, downloaded `hdf-4.2.12`, went to this directory and tried to configure it. Only then I got the following error:

   ```
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   /home/mala/hdf-4.2.12/bin/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
   Try `/home/mala/hdf-4.2.12/bin/missing --help' for more information
   configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
   checking for gawk... no
   checking for mawk... mawk
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
   checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
   checking shell variables initial values... done
   checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking if basename works... yes
   checking if xargs works... yes
   checking for config x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu... no
   checking for config x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu... no
   checking for config unknown-linux-gnu... no
   checking for config unknown-linux-gnu... no
   checking for config x86_64-linux-gnu... no
   checking for config x86_64-linux-gnu... no
   checking for config x86_64-unknown... no
   checking for config linux-gnu... found
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
   checking for gcc... gcc
   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
   checking for suffix of executables... 
   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
   checking for suffix of object files... o
   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
   checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
   checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
   checking for style of include used by make... GNU
   checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
   checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
   checking for g++... g++
   checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
   checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
   checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
   checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
   checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
   checking how to get verbose linking output from gfortran... -v
   checking for Fortran 77 libraries of gfortran...  -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../.. -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
   checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
   checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... lower case, underscore, no extra underscore
   checking if Java JNI interface enabled... no
   checking whether ln -s works... yes
   checking for ar... ar
   checking for bison... bison -y
   checking for flex... flex
   checking for diff... diff -w
   checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
   checking for neqn... neqn
   checking for tbl... tbl
   checking how to print strings... printf
   checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
   checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
   checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
   checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
   checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
   checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
   checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
   checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
   checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
   checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
   checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
   checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
   checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
   checking for objdump... objdump
   checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
   checking for dlltool... no
   checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
   checking for archiver @FILE support... @
   checking for strip... strip
   checking for ranlib... ranlib
   checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
   checking for sysroot... no
   checking for mt... mt
   checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
   checking for ANSI C header files... yes
   checking for sys/types.h... yes
   checking for sys/stat.h... yes
   checking for stdlib.h... yes
   checking for string.h... yes
   checking for memory.h... yes
   checking for strings.h... yes
   checking for inttypes.h... yes
   checking for stdint.h... yes
   checking for unistd.h... yes
   checking for dlfcn.h... yes
   checking for objdir... .libs
   checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
   checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
   checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
   checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
   checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
   checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
   checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
   checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
   checking for shl_load... no
   checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
   checking for dlopen... no
   checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
   checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
   checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... no
   checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
   checking whether to build shared libraries... no
   checking whether to build static libraries... yes
   checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
   checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
   checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
   checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
   checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
   checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
   checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
   checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
   checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
   checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
   checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
   checking whether to build shared libraries... no
   checking whether to build static libraries... yes
   checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fPIC
   checking if gfortran PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
   checking if gfortran static flag -static works... yes
   checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
   checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
   checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
   checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
   configure: creating ./config.lt
   config.lt: creating libtool
   checking if we should install only statically linked executables... no
   checking zlib.h usability... yes
   checking zlib.h presence... yes
   checking for zlib.h... yes
   checking for compress2 in -lz... yes
   checking for compress2... yes
   checking jpeglib.h usability... yes
   checking jpeglib.h presence... yes
   checking for jpeglib.h... yes
   checking for jpeg_start_decompress in -ljpeg... yes
   checking for szlib... suppressed
   checking for xdr library support... yes
   checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
   checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
   checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
   checking whether gfortran understands -c and -o together... yes
   checking size of int*... 8
   checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
   checking for build mode... production
   checking for math library support... yes
   checking for fork... yes
   checking for system... yes
   checking for vfork... yes
   checking for wait... yes
   checking if deprecated public symbols are available... yes
   checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: creating libhdf4.settings
   config.status: creating hdf/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/examples/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/fortran/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/fortran/examples/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/src/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/test/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/util/Makefile
   config.status: creating hdf/util/h4cc
   config.status: creating hdf/util/h4fc
   config.status: creating hdf/util/h4redeploy
   config.status: creating hdf/util/testutil.sh
   config.status: error: cannot find input file: man/Makefile.in'
   ```

I am using Ubuntu version 17.04. How can I remove this error?

Comment: Did you do a `./configure` and/or `sudo make`? If yes, then your source code is incomplete.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @heynnema. I tried to do  ./configure only then I got the following error. What does source code imcomplete mean?

Comment: Source incomplete means that you're missing some files. The first error is `/home/mala/hdf-4.2.12/bin/missing`, and then there's `config.status: error: cannot find input file: man/Makefile.in`

Comment: @heynnema.Thank you . Is there a way I could remove this error?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have edited my question and tried to explain what i did exactly.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *exact* commands that led to the program output in question?

Comment: I see that the Python import issue is rather different from the original one. Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you're broadening their scope which makes them harder to answer. I took the liberty to revert the edit that adds the follow-up question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster  As you said , I have asked a new question .https://askubuntu.com/questions/927285/cant-import-pyhdf this is the link .

Comment: @heynnema You should not use `sudo` for a regular `make` (you might need it for `make install`)

Comment: @gerrit yeah... that was almost 2 years ago, and I know better now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build the HDF4 library from source in Ubuntu. You can simply install it and its development files from the package `libhdf4-dev`.

Additionally you can also install a Python module for HDF**5** from the packages `python-h5py` (Python 2.7) or `python3-h5py` (Python 3).

Comment: I did what you told. After  installing these libraries and modules I am still not able to import pyhdf module. Am I missing something?I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have edited my question . Could you please tell me what mistake I did?