# Can't import pyhdf

Tags: python, libraries

I need to read the MODIS HDF4 file that I downloaded from the site https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/ search for my project. I need to write a python program using the Pyhdf module to open and read the file so, I installed the library `libhdf4-dev` and the module `python-h5py` as said here [Error:cannot find input file: `man/Makefile.in'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927083/errorcannot-find-input-file-man-makefile-in). After doing all these I am still not able to import pyhdf. when I try to import pyhdf using the command `import pyhdf`. I get the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-1-c77c3400983d>", line 1, in <module>
import pyhdf 
ImportError: No module named pyhdf
```

How can I import pyhdf?

Comment: output of `which pip` please.

Comment: `python-h5py` provides the python module `h5py`. It's *an* interface to the HDF5 library but I'm not sure if that is the one you need. Do you need it for an existing Python program or are you going to write your own? Based on what context do you need the module `pyhdf`?

Comment: @Ravexina pip for python 2.7 .At first I tried to install pyhdf directly by using `pip install pyhdf`  but I got error . this is the follow up of the following question  https://askubuntu.com/questions/927083/errorcannot-find-input-file-man-makefile-in

Comment: @DavidFoerster I need to read the MODIS HDF4 file that I downloaded from the site https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/ for research purpose. I need to write a python program using the Pyhdf module to open and read the file.

Comment: As far as I can tell `libhdf5` and its Python interface `h5py` can open HDF4 data files. If you're going to write a new program anyway you may be better off with `h5py` because it adds the benefit of being able to handle HDF5 data. Also, could you please [edit] your question when you want to add information or clarify something? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Thnak you . I am new to this site too so I am having difficulty .But, I will try to do what you said